# How to store GeoLocation in Firestore using Google Apps Script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store location in firebase cloud firestore from google sheets using Google Apps Script but I haven't any idea that how to use GeoPoint.

Here my code for add data Google Sheets to Firestore

```
function addData() {

    const email = "client email";
    const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPrivate Key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    const projectId = "project id";

    var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

    var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()]

    var sourceData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows, columns).getValues()

    var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < sourceLen; i++) {

        var data = {};

        var lat = sourceData[i][0];
        var long = sourceData[i][1];

        data.lat = lat;
        data.long = long;

        firestore.createDocument("locations", data);

    }
}
```

How can I add this lat/long GeoPoint in Firestore using Google Apps Script?

Comment: It's good practice to use `let` instead of `var` with the new V8 Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same properties of a GeoPoint in your solution to have it treated like one.

```js
data.latitude = lat;
data.longitude = long;
```

[Source](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/blob/c8641b1801c1935f7eef7c864f28e0ad18bcaa06/Document.ts#L150)

***Disclaimer:** I am a contributor to this library*

Comment: Thanks brother!! It's working and it's store lat/long geopoint. But it's not generate geoHash.

Comment: @DarshanPrajapati What is a GeoHash? Can you link to some definition?

Answer (score 3):

if you want the field to be a proper geopoint, you need to define a geopoint class as follows:

```
class geopoint {
  constructor(lat, lon) {
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = lon;
  }
}
```

then, you can do this in your code:

```
data.location = new geopoint(1, 1);
```

The result will be

[image: a proper geopoint]